# mariadb10.1にリストアすると一回目だけ失敗して、データベース再作成後に再度リストアすると成功する

Tags: mariadb

mariadb5.5から10.1へのバージョンアップを行っています。
5.5から出力したダンプファイルを10.1にリストアするのですが、一回目のリストアでは必ず失敗し、一度データベースを削除、再作成した後のリストアでは成功する、という現象に悩まされています。
エラーの内容は

> ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 44811: The user specified as a definer ('batch'@'localhost') does not exist

なのですが、'batch'@'localhost'は確かに存在しており、実際ユーザーを追加せずとも同じダンプファイルで2回目のリストアは成功します。
実際に使用しているコマンドは以下の通りです。

```
// mariadb5.5にて
$ mysqldump -u root -p -x -h localhost -R --opt --quick databasename | gzip > /root/backup_db/databasename.sql.gz
$ mysqldump -u root -p -x -h localhost --allow-keywords mysql | gzip > /root/backup_db/mysql.sql.gz

// mariadb10.1をインストール後
$ mysql_secure_installation
$ mysql_upgrade -u root -p
$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost
# create database databasename;
# \q
// 圧縮されていたダンプファイルを解凍後
$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost mysql < mysql.sql
$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost databasename< databasename.sql // ここで必ず失敗する

$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost
# drop database databasename;
# create database databasename;
# \q

$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost databasename< databasename.sql // ここは成功する
```

原因として考えられること、確認すべきこと等ありましたらご教示いただきたく思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーメッセージで検索すると以下のページがヒットします。 https://www.softel.co.jp/blogs/tech/archives/5041

Comment: @cubick 
ありがとうございます。
今回存在しないと言われている'batch'@'localhost'はリストア先に存在しており、特にユーザーを追加等せず同じダンプファイルで再リストアすると成功しております。
そのため、何か別の原因があるのではと考えております。

Comment: mysql データベースをインポート後、"FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" が必要なのでは？

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya ありがとうございます。結論`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`が必要だったようです。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76651657/restoring-to-mariadb10-1-fails-the-first-time-but-succeeds-when-restoring-again
で頂いたコメントの通り、mysqlデータベースをリストア後、`mysql_upgrade`を実行したらエラーが出なくなりました（`mysql_upgrade`は最後に`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`を実行する）。皆様本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

結論としては `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` が必要だったようです。

[英語版でも同じ内容で投稿](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76651657/2322778) しており、そちらで頂いたコメントの通り、データベースをリストア後、`mysql_upgrade` を実行したらエラーが出なくなりました。
（`mysql_upgrade` は最後に `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` を実行する）

---

*この投稿は [@snks さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/95547/mariadb10-1%e3%81%ab%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%82%a2%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8%e4%b8%80%e5%9b%9e%e7%9b%ae%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e5%a4%b1%e6%95%97%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6-%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%83%99%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b9%e5%86%8d%e4%bd%9c%e6%88%90%e5%be%8c%e3%81%ab%e5%86%8d%e5%ba%a6%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%82%a2%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8%e6%88%90%e5%8a%9f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b#comment109357_95547) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*